# Unnecessary curly bracket

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I am trying to use postloader with webpack 4 as following:

```
   test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "css-loader"
      },
      {
        loader: "postcss-loader"
      },
      {
        loader: "sass-loader",
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          includePaths: ["node_modules", "node_modules/@material/*"].map(
            d => path.join(__dirname, d)
          )
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

I have to include `node_modules`, because of https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web

The `index.scss` file:

```
@import "./Topbar/scss/topbar.scss";
@import "./Sidebar/scss/sidebar.scss";

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.scss
Module build failed: Syntax Error

(1:6) Unnecessary curly bracket

> 1 | body {
    |      ^
  2 |   margin: 0;
  3 |   padding: 0; }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
I change from `test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/` to `test: /\.scss$/` and the content of `index.scss` remains the same:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The compiler still complain:

```
    ERROR in ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-3!./src/index.scss)
    Module build failed: Syntax Error

    (1:6) Unnecessary curly bracket

    > 1 | body {
        |      ^
      2 |   margin: 0;
      3 |   padding: 0; }

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

**Update 2**

That is the whole configuration:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const glob = require("glob");


module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.[hash].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          },
          /*{
            loader: "postcss-loader"
          },*/
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              includePaths: ["node_modules", "node_modules/@material/*", "src"].map(
                d => path.join(__dirname, d)
              )
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name][hash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: "public"
      }
    ])
  ]
};
```

Comment: Remove everything from the `index.scss` except the import,try to load the styles only which you are importing, it may happen because of the issues in other file

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: The `includePaths` that you are using, refers to scss files or sass files? The problem is that the loader is trying to compile your scss with a sass syntax. Why do you test your files as sass or scss? Do you have any sass files in your project?

Comment: I did not have any `.sass` file in my project. I updated my post

Comment: Can you post the code of the two includes?

Comment: Topbar and sidebar are include files that you created or part of some third party plugin?

Comment: I don't understand this, but maybe this helps, If yes please post an answer how: https://github.com/postcss/postcss/issues/1062